# Performance when Reading single byte vs many at a time?

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm trying to compare `InputStream.read()` vs `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` in terms of performance.

Is `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` faster in some way, given the `read(b, off, len)` method for class `InputStream` simply calls the method `read()` repeatedly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't confuse what is the default behaviour of InputStream and what most of its subclasses do. A principle of OO design is that sub-classes can change the behaviour of a method for that implementation.

From InputStream - read(byte[]) calls read() repeatedly.

```
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
   // code removed

        for (; i < len ; i++) {
            c = read();

   // code removed
}
```

From BufferedInputStream - read(byte[]) does not call read().

```
public synchronized int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
   // code removed
        int nread = read1(b, off + n, len - n);
   // code removed
}

private int read1(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
   // code removed
            return getInIfOpen().read(b, off, len);
   // code removed
}
```

From FileInputStream - read(byte[]) does not call read().

```
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    return readBytes(b, off, len);
}

private native int readBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

While InputStream will read one byte at a time, almost all the implementations will pass read(byte[]) to the same method in the underlying stream.

Note: the implementations for read(byte[], int, int) are different in all three cases.

> What i mean to ask more clearly is: Let's say i want to read 20 bytes, Reading one byte at a time will hit underlying stream (e.g. file system) every time in a loop that means 20 times..ok Now reading array of 20 bytes in one go, i.e using read(byte[] 20), Now that's gonna hit underlying stream (e.g. file system) one time or 20 times..?? (as it's given: read(byte[] b) method is also going to call the method read() repeatedly 20 times) ??

Whether you use BufferedInputStream or FileInputStream, one read(byte[]) results in atmost one system call to read into the byte[].

Comment: PeterLawrey: Thanks for that well distinguished explanation .. So does that mean all 3 methods of InputStream will read atmost one byte at a time, irrespective of the number of bytes we specify in read(byte[]) ??

Comment: No, I am trying to demonstrate at length and in detail why this is NOT the case. It is not clear to me why you might believe this could be the case.

Comment: one more thing, if using  **BufferedInputStream** rather, any advantage of creating a byte buffer and reading  with read(byte[]) method, as opposed to reading it byte by byte?

Comment: There is *much* less advantage. It can still be slightly faster to use read(byte[]) as this calls BufferedInputStream less often.  Note: if you are reading large buffers like 16KB or more, using a BufferedInputStream might not help (if its buffer is smaller)

Comment: Peter Lawrey thanks a lot,  is there any  dafault buffer size BufferedInputStream uses or holds with simple read() method call, or that is internally it builds up seeing data size, i mean without specifying buffer size explicitly.

Comment: The default size of the HotSpot JVM is 8192 bytes (you can see this is the source) Other JVMs could be different, but it is unlikely to matter what the exact size is.  You can set it if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Use whichever you find most convenient in your case but remember to wrap your `InputStream` with `BufferedInputStream`.

Without buffering single `read()` will hit underlying stream (e.g. file system) every time you read. With buffering the same `read()` loads a chunk (e.g. 4KiB) and buffers it. Obviously reading from disk (even if some lower-lever OS/hard disk caching is present) is much slower.

Therefore `read(byte[] b)` is better only if your stream is not buffered - or if you really want to read more than one byte.

Comment: Reading it a character/byte at a time (that is InputStream.read()),
or reading it a byte/char array a block at a time..what's the difference when read(byte[] b) method is also going to call the method read() repeatedly byte/char array a block declared times?

Comment: @ Tomasz Nurkiewicz: thanks but exclude the case of BufferedInputStream.
If we only talk about InputStream..then both methods would result in  equal performance..is it true to say?

Comment: @AshishKataria You're just repeating the original question here, and he's already answered it. If you interpose a `BufferedInputStream,` there are no single-byte read operations into the operation, that being what it is for.

Comment: @EJP..thanks
But Forget about BufferedInputStream for an instance:

What i mean to ask more clearly is:
Let's say i want to read 20 bytes,
Reading one byte at a time will hit underlying stream (e.g. file system) every time in a loop that means 20 times..ok

Now reading array of 20 bytes in one go, i.e using read(byte[] 20), Now that's gonna hit underlying stream (e.g. file system) one time or 20 times..?? (as it's given: read(byte[] b) method is also going to call the method read() repeatedly 20 times) ??

Comment: @AshishKataria Your statement "...`read(byte[] b)` method is also going to call the method read() repeatedly..." is false.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

is referring:The read(b, off, len) method for class InputStream simply calls the method read() repeatedly.

Comment: @AshishKataria You are citing an abstract class. Please cite a concrete implementation class that **doesn't override** that method.